# Magento 1.9.3 does not send orders mail - corrupted database?

Tags: magento-1

Can a database error cause not to send order mails?

I do not know when, magento stopped sending me emails when the customer orders. They do not come to me, not to the customer. Only mails with orders do not come. All other (shipping, etc.) are coming. Cron set correctly.

I installed a new magento installation with trial data. Without cron settings, test orders send emails. When I am modifying my products or changing the database, emails confirming the order do not send.

I'm fighting this for two months. I gave up. Magento v 1.9.3.0